# Can I convert a string into a class with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

Imagine you have a bunch of classes that to access you need to do

```
ModuleA::ModuleB::ActualClassName
```

What I'd like is to bypass the `ModuleA::ModuleB` part and just type `ActualClassName` and have it know what im talking about.

There is 1:1 on files to classes so I am using Dir to navigate to the directory and create an array of string class names that I would like to convert to a variable.

## tl;dr

given `["ClassOne", "ClassTwo"]` make it so that

`ClassOne == ModuleA::ModuleB::ClassOne` and `ClassTwo == ModuleA::ModuleB::ClassTwo`

The essential goal of this is to make my life easier on the Rails console.

EDIT: I see there is much confusion around what I've truly asked for, in part due to my own misuse of Ruby terminology.  Instead I will propose a "fill-in-the-blank" type solution.

Assume that `ModuleA::ModuleB::ClassOne` and `ModuleA::ModuleB::ClassTwo` are defined classes

```
classes = ["ClassOne", "ClassTwo"]
# insert ruby magic here
ClassOne == ModuleA::ModuleB::ClassOne # true
ClassTwo == ModuleA::ModuleB::ClassTwo # true
```

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing what this has to do with local variables.

Comment: And what does this have to do with converting strings into local variables? What does it even *mean* to "convert a string into a local variable"?

Comment: it means i have a string "ClassOne" and i want to execute ruby code that does the exact same thing as saying ClassOne = ModuleA::ModuleB::ClassOne .   except it must be based on the string litera

Comment: This is impossible. Local variable names *must* start with a lowercase letter, that is what *makes* them local variables. However, the strings in your array start with capital letters, ergo, what you want is obviously impossible.

Comment: ah ok so i suppose 'local variable' is the wrong name and perhaps 'constant' is more correct?  if you open irb and say Abc = 1 and then type Abc it returns 1, so on some level Abc is now a named variable.  perhaps my lingo is not as ruby specific as it could be but conceptually is this impossible?

Answer (score 3):

```
classes = ['ClassOne', 'ClassTwo']

classes.each {|klass| Object.const_set(klass, ModuleA::ModuleB.const_get(klass))}

puts ClassOne == ModuleA::ModuleB::ClassOne # => true
puts ClassTwo == ModuleA::ModuleB::ClassTwo # => true
```

Is this not what you're looking for? Ref: [Module#const_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Module.html#method-i-const_get), [Modulet#const_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Module.html#method-i-const_set)

Comment: no i am trying to avoid having to manually define the class as C, and rather use ruby metaprogramming to iterate through an array of strings that represent module scoped class names and have them stored as top level class names.  i made an edit to the original question with more clarification

Comment: @nick, Edited my answer.

Comment: sorry i have been away for the holidays, that is exactly what i was looking for thank you and happy new year!

Comment: My pleasure @nick, and Happy New Year to you too!  If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

to answer the question you're asking in the title of the question ("can I convert a string into a local variable"),

```
a = "hello"
thing_i_care_about = "a"
send(thing_i_care_about) # "hello"
```

but, to answer the question you ask in the body of the question (requires ActiveSupport, which is included with Rails)

```
mod_string = "ModuleA::ModuleB::"
klass = "ClassOne"
mod = "#{mod_string}#{klass}".safe_constantize
```

`String#safe_constantize` will return nil if it raises an error.

https://apidock.com/rails/String/safe_constantize

Comment: maybe the question isnt as clear as i thought.
i am trying to take an array of strings, and make it so each string now becomes a local variable name representing its class that is nested within modules

Comment: This is impossible. Local variable names *must* start with a lowercase letter, that is what *makes* them local variables. However, the strings in your array start with capital letters, ergo, what you want is obviously impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.const_get` :

```
$irb
2.4.1 :001 > class Foo; end; classname='Foo'; p Object.const_get(classname).new 
#<Foo:0x007fd91f0db790>
 => #<Foo:0x007fd91f0db790>
```

As you can see I created a class, stored its name in a variable and created a new object of that class using a variable. That's very handy when you want to change implementation of a given class.

Comment: i am trying to achieve this when class Foo is nested within several modules, such that at the top level within rails console i can access ModuleA::ModuleB::Foo using just  Foo

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of a constant using the appropriately named [`Module#const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-const_get) method and set it using the also well-named [`Module#const_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-const_set) method:

```
classes.each |klass| do
  Object.const_set(klass, ModuleA::ModuleB.const_get(klass))
end
```